# Winsorizing Panel Data (dataframe) by year and Trimming for certain conditions

Tags: r, outliers, panel-data

I'm trying to winsorize (replacing outliers with values that are 2 or 3 standard deviations away from the mean) on panel data and for each year. I installed the robustHD package which includes such a function, however I'm unable to implement it on my dataset.

My dataset looks similar to Grunfeld (although I have NA's) with different firms over the same years. (1935-1954)

```
> head(Grunfeld, 6)
  firm year   inv  value capital
1    1 1935 317.6 3078.5     2.8
2    1 1936 391.8 4661.7    52.6
3    1 1937 410.6 5387.1   156.9
4    1 1938 257.7 2792.2   209.2
5    1 1939 330.8 4313.2   203.4
6    1 1940 461.2 4643.9   207.2
```

What i would like to do now is to winsorize only certain columns (i.e. inv and value) over all firms and store it in a dataframe with the same structure. I tried the following code:

## The goal is basically to obtain a winsorized copy of the original dataframe (everything structured in the same way).

As proposed below, plyr is a good way to split dataframes and apply functions but i'm unable to get it to work.

```
library(plm)
library(robustHD)
library(plyr)

data("Grunfeld", package="plm")

#Winsorize data  each year (over all firms) therefore split dataframe for each year and apply the winsorize function)

Grunfeld.w<-ddply(Grunfeld, .(year) function(x) winsorize(x$inv,x$value))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list to store data frames beforehand. The list needs to be of length n, where n is the number of unique values in year.

```
library(plm)
library(robustHD)
data("Grunfeld", package="plm")

## determine unique values in year and their length
unique_years <- unique(Grunfeld$year)
n_unique_years <- length(unique_years)

## create an empty list of length 20
Grunfeld.w <- vector("list", length=n_unique_years)

for(i in 1:n_unique_years){
  Grunfeld.w[[i]]  <- winsorize(subset(Grunfeld, year==unique_years[i], 
                                       select=c(inv, value)))

  ## add the year field to each insorized data frame
  Grunfeld.w[[i]] <- cbind(Grunfeld.w[[i]], year=unique_years[i])
}
```

Now each winsorized data are stored in the Grunfeld.w list as a data frame. If you want just one data frame, then use the following:

```
## convert the list to one data frame
temp <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", Grunfeld.w))
```

As for your second question, I'm guessing that you want to select "subjects" based on some characteristic (e.g., >5000 in x) but you don't want to use the `subset` function. Then you can use the `dplyr`'s `filter` function.. Again let me use the Grunfeld data to illustrate:

```
library(dplyr)
Grunfeld_gt1940 <- filter(Grunfeld, year>1940) ## the "gt" stands for "greater than".
```

## Edited

If you want to arrange the new data in the same way as the original data, you can use `rownames` to extract the original order:

```
temp <- temp[order(as.numeric(rownames(temp))), ]

## Add the winsorized variables to the original data
names(temp)[1:2] <- c("inv_wins", "value_wins")
Grunfeld_new <- data.frame(Grunfeld, temp[, c("inv_wins", "value_wins")])
```

Comment: thank you for you answer! Somehow the conversion to a data.frame is not working. Also how is it possible to rearrange the winsorized data in the same way as the original data?

Comment: Actually, `do.call("rbind", Grunfeld.w)` converts the list into a matrix, not a data.frame. So I've corrected that error.

Comment: I tried to implement your code but unfortunately it is not compatible with my NA's and i get the following error: Error in eigen(R, symmetric = TRUE) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
> traceback()
6: stop("infinite or missing values in 'x'")
5: eigen(R, symmetric = TRUE)
4: winsorize.matrix(as.matrix(x, ...))
3: winsorize(as.matrix(x, ...))
2: winsorize.data.frame(subset(mydata, time == unique_years[i],

Comment: You can remove missing values and apply `winsorize`. Then include `na.omit` in the `winsorize` in the `for` loop. I think this is much more parsimonious than, say, imputing missing data and then winsorize them, which is hard to wrap my head around.

Comment: Where would you include `na.omit` and how can you remove missing values before that? Cheers