# R Winsorizing individual variables in different panel data years

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a problem that I can not fix myself, having tried multiple ways myself.

**Goal: I want to winsorize individual variables for different event years.**

That is, I want to winsorize all observations for variable var 1 (and var 2, var 3 etc.) for each event year (-5,-4,-3...+4,+5)

Imagine the following data structure (pdata.frame, object of the plm package, behaves similarly to a normal data frame as far as I am aware):

```
#firm-year observations with different numeric variables, sequences only for illustrative purposes, true variables are empirical observations
firms <- c(rep("firm a",11), rep("firm b", 11))
years <- seq(-5,5,1)
var1 <- seq(0,2.1,0.1)
var2 <- seq(0,21,1)
var3 <- seq(0,1,1/21)

#create panel data
df <- data.frame(cbind(firms,years,var1,var2,var3))
library(plm)
p.df <- pdata.frame(df, index=c("firms","years"))

# NAs in my variables exist 
p.df[12,3] = NA
p.df[10,5] = NA

p.df
```

My data frame then looks like this:

```
           firms years var1 var2               var3
firm a--1 firm a    -1  0.4    4   0.19047619047619
firm a--2 firm a    -2  0.3    3  0.142857142857143
firm a--3 firm a    -3  0.2    2 0.0952380952380952
firm a--4 firm a    -4  0.1    1 0.0476190476190476
firm a--5 firm a    -5    0    0                  0
firm a-0  firm a     0  0.5    5  0.238095238095238
firm a-1  firm a     1  0.6    6  0.285714285714286
firm a-2  firm a     2  0.7    7  0.333333333333333
firm a-3  firm a     3  0.8    8  0.380952380952381
firm a-4  firm a     4  0.9    9               <NA>
firm a-5  firm a     5    1   10  0.476190476190476
firm b--1 firm b    -1 <NA>   15  0.714285714285714
firm b--2 firm b    -2  1.4   14  0.666666666666667
firm b--3 firm b    -3  1.3   13  0.619047619047619
firm b--4 firm b    -4  1.2   12  0.571428571428571
firm b--5 firm b    -5  1.1   11  0.523809523809524
firm b-0  firm b     0  1.6   16  0.761904761904762
firm b-1  firm b     1  1.7   17   0.80952380952381
firm b-2  firm b     2  1.8   18  0.857142857142857
firm b-3  firm b     3  1.9   19  0.904761904761905
firm b-4  firm b     4    2   20  0.952380952380952
firm b-5  firm b     5  2.1   21                  1
```

My obviously has more observations and variables.

The closest solution I found was by [Masato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865857).
`robustHD::winsorize`, which Masato used, is not compatible with data that has NAs though. `DescTools:Winsorize` in turn does not accept data frames and will winsorize my data over all the variable columns which does not make sense.

I guess the solution lies somewhere in writing another for loop and using `DescTools::Winsorize` on the individual columns after having extracted them for single event years (-5 to +5).
Another way would be to make the `robustHD::winsorize` function somehow handle NAs and apply it to the whole frame of var1 to var3.

I highly appreciate your help on this and would love to here your suggestions.

Best regards,
cork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

````
library(tidyverse)

p.df%>%
  as.tibble()%>%
  group_by(years)%>%
  mutate(across(c(var1,var2,var3),as.double))%>%
  mutate(across(c(var1,var2,var3),~DescTools::Winsorize(.x,na.rm=T)))
```
````

Comment: Hello TobKel,
Thank you. It does not do the trick with winsorizing only e.g. year-5 values for only var3. I.e. it now winsorizes the whole var1 ... var 3 columns taking values from different years. I would like to winsorize for individual years and individual variables i.e. winsorize the set of all -5 and var1 observations and then all -4 and var 3 seperately and so on. The same for var2 and var3. e.g. given that I have 11 unique years (-5 to 5 incl 0) and 3 different variables, I want to winsorize 33 individual sets.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly. So do you want to group the individual years so that they are winsorized individually?

Comment: Yes, so I want to for example winsorize observations in year -5 for var 3 and do so separately for all years and variables.

Comment: See my updated version. (I've added `group_by(years)`)

Comment: yes, it works! I actually had written a working for function in the meantime and have now compared the output of my function to your suggestion. The results are the same. Thank you!